# Adding items from .csv and grouping them dynamically

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, grouping

I'm trying to create code entry for a user system.  Below is a small example of the code.  I can get the users and groups created based on a .csv (see below), but I can't find a good way of going into group membership mode, and adding those users based on the group that was added (associating the users to their respecting groups).

It needs to loop through the group names (based on unique entries--Not sure if this is the best way or not... possibly not).  So, let's pick on grade 11: go into grade 11 mode (dynamically, per unique list), and add all users that need to go into grade 11.  Sounds easy, haven't been able to find a way :\

```
$path="items.csv"
$All_grades = Import-Csv -path $path | sort grade -Unique 

Write-Host "config users"        #<<---Add Users from .csv

Import-Csv -path $path |

ForEach-Object
{
Write-Host edit id """$($_.id)"""
write-host set grade """$($_.grade)"""
Write-Host set username """$($_.username)"""
Write-Host next
}

Write-Host "config grades"      #<<-----Add Groups from .csv (unique groups)

ForEach ($_ in $All_grades)
{
Write-Host edit $_.grade
write-host set comment """$($_.comment)"""
Write-Host next
}

Write-Host "config group membership"       #<<----Add Group membership based on .csv

ForEach ($All_grades in $path){   #<------- Trying to pick a group from the .csv list, 
    foreach ($_ in $path) #<-------    then look at all usernames and assign correct grade for that user
{                        #<-------     but not working
Write-Host edit  #<------- 
Write-Host set member xy #<--- 
}}
```

This is how my .csv file looks like (items.csv):

```
id,username,grade,comment
21234,bsmith,10,tenth
21123,djohnson,12,twelveth
11223,jbliss,11,eleventh
21211,atwain,11,eleventh
```

Comment: I'm a little lost here. Why do you need to even group them? What not just use ForEach on the group and have a switch statement based on grade? You can use `Group-Object` but I don't see what based on what you are doing.

Comment: I'm trying to get this done 'on the fly',  with dozens of groups which might change in the future and hundreds of users needed to be added as members.   The code for this particular system needs to receive the group entry mode,  then based on which group is being edited,  add it's  members.  I wasn't aware of the group-object command,  will research.

Comment: I wonder why you are using `sort grade -Unique`. This will enforce, that there is exactly one user per grade in your csv. Other users are dropped. Are you sure that this is what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me, that [Group-Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/494af40a-1315-420f-8bd6-932006576dac%28v=wps.630%29.aspx) is what you want:

```
foreach ($gradeGroup in ($All_grades | Group-Object -Property Grade))
{
    Write-Host "Create group $($gradeGroup.Name)"
    foreach ($member in $gradeGroup.Group)
    {
        Write-Host "- Add $($member.username) to $($gradeGroup.Name)"
    } 
}
```

Comment: I believe this is what I need... now I'm trying to get the users in group 11 on the same line.   I put an example of this at the bottom of this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/VeHK2pYQ

Comment: Never mind, got it!  Thanks for introducing me to the Group-Object cmdlet!  (Final code here: http://pastebin.com/4AX3yLRt  (Should I include this somewhere in the question? -Not sure what the etiquette for that is).  Anyways, thanks!